# A case that shows a separable topological space is not normal

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let ($X,\tau$) be a separable topological space. If $X$ has a closed subspace $D$, which is equipotent to $\mathbb{R}$ (exists a bijection between $D$ and $\mathbb{R}$), and the induced topology on $D$ is discrete, then $X$ is not normal.

Could someone give me some ideas on how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: What is $R$?  Do you mean $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing out, I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an application of Jones’ lemma. Henno Brandsma proved the lemma in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170724/is-there-a-simple-method-to-prove-that-the-square-of-the-sorgenfrey-line-is-not/170740#170740), and the special case that you want is treated in [Dan Ma’s Topology Blog](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/jones-lemma/).

Before you look at those, though, here’s a HINT:

- If $X$ is normal, for each non-trivial subset $A$ of $D$ there is a continuous $f_A:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f_A[A]=\{0\}$ and $f[D\setminus A]=\{1\}$.
- If two continuous functions from $X$ to $[0,1]$ agree on a dense set, they are equal. How many functions are there from a countable set to $[0,1]$?